# Why when drawing a rectangle with the mouse on pictureBox.Image it's not drawing anything?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

pictureBoxSnap is winforms PictureBox regular control.
When it's getting to the part of:

```
pictureBoxSnap.Image = snap.Image;
```

It will not show/draw a rectangle on the pictureBoxSnap
But if it's getting to the second part of the IF to this line:

```
drawpicbox(this.listBox1.SelectedIndex);
```

It will draw a rectangle.

I have this selected index event

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowSnap snap = listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex] as WindowSnap;
            if (snap.Text.Contains("emails") || snap.Text.Contains("Emails"))
            {
                pictureBoxSnap.Image = snap.Image;
            }
            else
            {
                img = new Bitmap(pictureBoxSnap.Width, pictureBoxSnap.Height);
                imgClone = new Bitmap(pictureBoxSnap.Width, pictureBoxSnap.Height);
                Graphics g;
                using (g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
                {
                    g.Clear(Color.White);
                }
                pictureBoxSnap.Image = img;
                drawpicbox(this.listBox1.SelectedIndex);
            }
        }
```

Then the drawpicbox method that get int(index):

```
private void drawpicbox(int index)
        {
            Rectangle[] test = rectangles;            
            Graphics g, g1;
            Size sz;
            WindowSnap snap = this.listBox1.SelectedItem as WindowSnap;
            Bitmap testBmp;
            if (snap.Image != null)
            {
                using (g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
                {
                    g.Clear(Color.White);
                    sz = calculateSizeAndPosition(snap.Image.Size);
                    if (isCropped[index] == true)
                    {
                        ConfirmRectangle.Enabled = false;
                        Reset.Enabled = true;
                        using (testBmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height))
                        {
                            using (g1 = Graphics.FromImage(testBmp))
                            {
                                g1.Clear(Color.White);
                                g1.DrawImage(snap.Image, (int)((pictureBoxSnap.Width - sz.Width) / 2.0), (int)((pictureBoxSnap.Height - sz.Height) / 2.0), sz.Width, sz.Height);
                            }
                            g.DrawImage(testBmp, rectangles[index], rectangles[index], GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, rectangles[index]);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (rectangles[index].Width != 0)
                    {
                        cm.MenuItems[0].Enabled = true;
                        cm.MenuItems[1].Enabled = true;
                        cm.MenuItems[2].Enabled = true;
                        cm.MenuItems[3].Enabled = true;
                        ConfirmRectangle.Enabled = true;
                        g.DrawImage(snap.Image, (int)((pictureBoxSnap.Width - sz.Width) / 2.0), (int)((pictureBoxSnap.Height - sz.Height) / 2.0), sz.Width, sz.Height);
                        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, rectangles[index]);
                        Reset.Enabled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cm.MenuItems[0].Enabled = false;
                        cm.MenuItems[1].Enabled = false;
                        cm.MenuItems[2].Enabled = false;
                        cm.MenuItems[3].Enabled = false;
                        ConfirmRectangle.Enabled = false;
                        g.DrawImage(snap.Image, (int)((pictureBoxSnap.Width - sz.Width) / 2.0), (int)((pictureBoxSnap.Height - sz.Height) / 2.0), sz.Width, sz.Height);
                        Reset.Enabled = false;
                    }

                }

                pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();
            }
        }
```

And the mouse events down and move that i use to drawing the rectangle:

```
WindowSnap snap = null;
        Point screenCoordinates;
        Point pictureBoxSnapCoordinates;
        private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
           screenCoordinates = this.PointToScreen(pictureBoxSnap.Location);


            Control control = (Control)sender;
            screenCoordinates = control.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            pictureBoxSnap.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
            screenCoordinates = pictureBoxSnap.PointToScreen(e.Location);
            pictureBoxSnapCoordinates = e.Location;
            Graphics g;
            Size sz;

            if (isCropped[listBox1.SelectedIndex] == false && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                snap = this.listBox1.SelectedItem as WindowSnap;

                RectStartPoint = e.Location;

                sz = calculateSizeAndPosition(snap.Image.Size);

                using (g = Graphics.FromImage(imgClone))
                {
                    g.Clear(Color.White);
                    g.DrawImage(snap.Image, (int)((pictureBoxSnap.Width - sz.Width) / 2.0), (int)((pictureBoxSnap.Height - sz.Height) / 2.0), sz.Width, sz.Height);
                }
            }
        }
```

Mouse move

```
private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isCropped[listBox1.SelectedIndex] == false && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && e.Location != RectStartPoint)
            {
                DrawRectangle(e.Location);
            }
        }
```

And last the DrawRectangle method

```
private void DrawRectangle(Point pnt)
        {
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
            g.DrawImage(imgClone, 0, 0);

            if (pnt.X == RectStartPoint.X || pnt.Y == RectStartPoint.Y)
            {
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Firebrick, RectStartPoint.X, RectStartPoint.Y, pnt.X, pnt.Y);
            }
            else if (pnt.X > RectStartPoint.X && pnt.Y > RectStartPoint.Y) 
            {
                rect.X = RectStartPoint.X; rect.Y = RectStartPoint.Y; rect.Width = pnt.X - RectStartPoint.X; rect.Height = pnt.Y - RectStartPoint.Y;
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, rect);
            }
            else if (pnt.X > RectStartPoint.X && pnt.Y < RectStartPoint.Y) 
            {
                rect.X = RectStartPoint.X; rect.Y = pnt.Y; rect.Width = pnt.X - RectStartPoint.X; rect.Height = RectStartPoint.Y - pnt.Y;
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, rect);
            }
            else if (pnt.X < RectStartPoint.X && pnt.Y > RectStartPoint.Y) 
            {
                rect.X = pnt.X; rect.Y = RectStartPoint.Y; rect.Width = RectStartPoint.X - pnt.X; rect.Height = pnt.Y - RectStartPoint.Y;
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, rect);
            }
            else 
            {
                rect.X = pnt.X; rect.Y = pnt.Y; rect.Width = RectStartPoint.X - pnt.X; rect.Height = RectStartPoint.Y - pnt.Y;
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, rect);
            }

            g.Dispose();

            pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();
        }
```

Now i used a break point in the selected index event when it does either the part of the IF:

```
pictureBoxSnap.Image = snap.Image;
```

Or

```
drawpicbox(this.listBox1.SelectedIndex);
```

In the end both are getting to the DrawRectangle method to the line:

```
g.DrawLine(Pens.Firebrick, RectStartPoint.X, RectStartPoint.Y, pnt.X, pnt.Y);
```

But when its the `pictureBoxSnap.Image = snap.Image;` it's not drawing anything i don't see any rectangle on the pictureBoxSnap but when it's doing `drawpicbox(this.listBox1.SelectedIndex);` i see the rectangle on the pictureBoxSnap.

Not sure why.

Comment: Too much code. Use the debugger to see whre you get and where you don't. Do you really need all those many many bitmaps?? What is the purpose of the class level variables? In `DrawRectangle` I don#t see how you change the Picuturebox's Image. You need to set it again after changing it!

Comment: I didn't understand the DrawRectangle part. Could you show me please how to change the pictureBoxSnap image and how to set it again ? About the Bitmaps and class level vars you right i'm about to organize .

Comment: Before (or maybe even instead of) `pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();` write `pictureBoxSnap.Image = img;`